# Tinymce- Text format not transferred through copy and paste

Tags: copy, tinymce, paste, tinymce-4

While working on the project, i found an issue :
*"When texts with certain format is copied, it should be pasted to replace the formatting of whichever line of text it will be placed in"*

**Steps To Reproduce**

- Copy unbolded text
- Go to line with bolded text
- Paste next to that word or paste by pressing enter to move in next
  line.

**Current behavior**
-Underlined UNBOLDED text is also bold when paste next to bolded text.

**Expected behavior**
-Underlined UNBOLDED text should be underlined and unbolded after paste.

**Used:
Tinymce version : 4.6.6**

*Same Thing i have tested in MS Word or any other text editor, the expected output is not same as the tinymce. So i have reported this as an issue*
[github link](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4408)

Please help
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected.  When you copy text with underline applied you are copying HTML like following:

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">fadsfasdfasd</span>
```

If you then paste that anywhere else in your document you have that HTML within the paragraph in question such as:

```
<p>
  <strong>fadsfasdfasdfa
    <span style="text-decoration:underline;">fadsfasdfasd</span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

So the net result is the outer strong tag also impacts the pasted text.  This is simply how HTML works and is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank You. But, due to different behaviour in other text editors i thought this might not be the correct working scenario for the tinymce.